# Maps V2 with viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-maps-v2

I'm currently developing for Android 4.3.
**Background:** 
I'm using pageViewer to scroll between three different fragments.
My second fragment (tab 2) has XML with SupportMapFragment and other content. as shown below : 
 [My problem http://imageupload.co.uk/files/vrhg1e06x977rkm1vhmd.jpg](http://imageupload.co.uk/files/vrhg1e06x977rkm1vhmd.jpg)

**My Attempt:**
While searching the web I noticed that for SupportMapFragment I need FragmentActivity which doesn't apply for FragmentPagerAdapter.
I need the user to have the ability to control the map as well as control the rest of the content in the fragment.

**My Question:**
How can I use the SupportMapFragment with the viewPager while having more content in the Fragment?

**More about my code:**
in the getItem inside FragmentPagerAdapter I'm returning Singleton Fragments (each Fragment has a class) therefore I couldn't find any solution over the Internet since my class can't extend SupportMapFragment because it has more data.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since Android 4.2 (also in the support library for pre-Jelly) you can use [nested fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments).

You can see how to create such fragment is:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private SupportMapFragment fragment;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_with_map, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (map == null) {
            map = fragment.getMap();
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)));
        }
    }
}
```

Above code copied from [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5064#c1).

Impoatant note: your custom `Fragments`'s layout cannot contain `<fragment>` tag.

Comment: what is the content of map_container then?

Comment: @AdrianOlar `map_container` is usually as `FrameLayout` that will host fragments added via code like in the above example.

Comment: i dont know exactly, but i used to use this code
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

this is not working. then i used you code. working well