# Android, main activity with drawer and google map as fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-maps-v2, navigation-drawer

I use one main activity, where I was implemented the `NavigationDrawer` as menu where I choose items (map, settings and few others) which are separated fragments. So I have one activity and many fragments. I put the map fragment to layout (xml file) within `RelativeLayout` and I have class which extends `Fragment` and in main activity I use this fragment like this:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, map).commit();
```

Where `content_frame` is a `FrameLayout` in activity_home.xml.

And layout for map fragment (fragment_map.xml) looks like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <fragment
            android:id="@+id/my_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is it a good approach, what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good approach.

You cannot nest `Fragment`s in other `Fragment`s layout's xml. More about it in [the official documentation on NestedFragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments).

For an example implementation see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18375626/2183804

Comment: Yes, I read about is, but everything works fine in my app. I also read and saw the examples where were a nested fragments so I was confused.

Comment: @PiotrKozlowski Does it work if you select map from the drawer, than something else and then map again?

Comment: I had a problem with this at the beginning, but I solved it and now everything works fine.

Comment: @PiotrKozlowski Hey can you please help me with same query i am still not getting output.